# Align numeric values to the right (recfmt output)

Tags: bash, text-formatting

I'm making a Unix database in a plain text with GNU Recutils. With the following script I get a books list of a selected category:

```bsh
recsel -t book -e "Category='$1'" "$RECFILE" | recfmt -f bycat.templ
```

The output is the following:

```
1: Book title
2: Book title
55: Book title
128: Book title
```

The file `bycat.templ` has the following content:

```
{{Id}}: {{Title}} (read: {{Read}})
```

It seems it's impossible to define the alignment to the right side from this file, according to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/manual/recutils.html#Generating-Reports).

So I try to find a Unix solution, probably using `printf`, `awk`, `xargs` or perhaps a `for` bucle for every line. I don't know how to achieve this.

The desired output:

```
  1: Book title
  2: Book title
 55: Book title
128: Book title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

File: `book.awk`

```c
BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
}
{
    id = $1
    $1 = ""
    sub(/^ +/, "", $0)
    printf("%3d: %s\n", id, $0)
}
```

Execution:

```bsh
recsel ... | recfmt ... | awk -f book.awk
```

Output:

```
  1: Book title
  2: Book title
 55: Book title
128: Book title
```

Comment: Totally awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I think _printf("%3d:_ will align numeric values to the right for the first 999 books. Don't know the size of the database and if it poses a problem.

Comment: It would be interesting to get the length of the highest value and apply this length as variable, in substitution for the `3` number. I'm not sure if I should get the length for this output (1st column) or directly the highest value of the `Id` field (with bash and the command recsel), mixing bash and awk.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it will remove the `colon " : "` if there is one in the book title (or elsewhere after the `ID`). Maybe it needs an Output Field Separator (`OFS`).

Comment: @Gounou correct (mostly), it'll replace every `:` in a book title with a blank char. It'd be more efficient to just not cause that replacement to occur than set OFS so the `:`s got replaced with themselves but that definitely would be one workaround except that you'd then need to change the `sub(/^ +/` too since the line would then start with a colon instead of a blank. The most important caveat here IMHO is that it will fail if any of the IDs can be 4 or more digits long and leave leading blanks if they can be 1 or 2 digits long.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-pass approach using any awk in any shell on every Unix box no matter how may digits are in the ID and no matter which characters can be present in a title (including `:`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    id = title = $0
    sub(/ *:.*/,"",id)
    sub(/[^:]*: */,"",title)
}
NR==FNR {
    wid = length(id)
    maxWid = (maxWid > wid ? maxWid : wid)
    next
}
{ printf "%*s: %s\n", maxWid, id, title }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
  1: Book title
  2: Book title
 55: Book title
128: Book title
```

Comment: file file -> file ?

Comment: @Gounou No, as I mentioned it's a 2-pass approach. First pass to determine the longest width of the ID field, second pass to print using that width.